# How to send the image uri to firebase?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been trying to send the uri to firebase but not able to get the correct data. What can i use within the success listener?

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view, int height, int width) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable != null)
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

And below:

```
public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    final String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(calendar.getTime());

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("storage details");
    StorageReference imagesRef = storageRef.child("details");

    UploadTask uploadTask = imagesRef.putBytes(data);
    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
           
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {



        }
    });
}
```

How to get the uri from the screenshot?

Comment: are you trying to save a URI object to firebase?

Comment: Yes that is what i am trying to do

Comment: in a app i tired to save the Uri to a file but couldn't i think it can not be done , what you can do is call `toString()` and save the string and to create the Uri by calling `Uri.parse(string)`, also you are saying you can not save the Uri but the is not code in your question where you're trying to do that

Answer (score 1):

You can get the storage url like below:

```
 uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            throw task.getException();
                        }
                        return storageRef.getDownloadUrl();
                    }
                }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        
                    }
                });
```

Once you get the url in onSuccess function then you can save it firebase database.

Comment: You can give upvote if you got the answer. I don't understand the second part in your comment !

Comment: he is asking about saving the Uri to a file